# Reasons a cronjob won't run every minute

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I've looked over many SO threads on cronjobs and can't figure out why my simple cronjob only runs once and doesn't repeat after each minute.

here's my cronjob setup:

```
html$ crontab -e //directory where my web application resides   
*/1 * * * * php index.php cronjob everyMinute  //command inside crontab  
html$ php index.php cronjob everyMinute  //run script
```

Here's my PHP script (my web application uses the Codeigniter framework but that doesn't seem relevant):

```
function everyMinute(){
    if($this->input->is_cli_request()){
        $count="i can count everyMinute".time();
        echo " {$count}!".PHP_EOL;                              
        file_put_contents("test.txt","Counted $count\n", FILE_APPEND);
    }       
}
```

Comment: do you really need */1 instead of a *

Comment: I'm not sured but as I know "* * * * * php index.php cronjob everyMinute" will executes command every minute. So, no need to put */1

Comment: Does it run at all? Looks like you run it once yourself?

Comment: where is index.php located? Give the full path in the crontab.

Comment: Make sure you put the complete path for the file also. Crontab does need absolute paths.

Comment: @JonStirling when i do this `html$ php index.php cronjob everyMinute` it outputs the timestamp to the test.txt 1 time. There are no new timestamps appended every minute, nor is the first timestamp overwritten but newer ones.

Comment: @palindrom and -@fedorqui, why would full path matter? If it works once, why couldn't it find it again?

Comment: @timpeterson because it is not the same executing from prompt than doing from crontab. Crontab needs absolute paths. It does not matter the directory from which you are editing crontab, it takes everything from /.

Comment: @AndreyTykhonov and -@palindrom, either `*/1` or `*` works as the first digit according to many Stackoverflow threads.

Comment: -@fedorqui, ok thanks, let me try adding the full path to the crontab

Comment: -@fedorqui, unfortunately that didn't work. ugh. any other thoughts? Here's how I changed the crontab: `*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /Applications/MNPP/Library/nginx/html/index.php cronjob everyMinute`

Comment: @timpeterson check executing permissions, just in case. Also, check if  the user executing cronjob is in /etc/cron.d/deny, in which case would  not be able to use it.
Try also with a simple `* * * * * touch /tmp/test_stack` to see if it manages to perform this cron.

Comment: @fedorqui, how do I run this simple test after adding it to my crontab?

Comment: Write `crontab -e` and in crontab write `* * * * * touch /tmp/test_stack` then save and exit.

Comment: `$ vim /tmp/test_stack` shows an empty file, what should it read?

Comment: `touch` just creates the file, does not fill it. Delete it and wait one minute. Then check if it has been created with `ls -l /tmp/test_stack`. If it does exist, means that you have permissions to use cron and we will be somewhere further then now : )

Comment: ok, now I understand. Yes I have permission to use cron. I just created a couple files this way.

Comment: Good. Try executing `/usr/bin/php /Applications/MNPP/Library/nginx/html/index.php cronjob everyMinute` manually. If it works, the same code in cronjob should. You can also try to put `"cronjob everyMinute"` (between quotes).

Comment: yeah executing manually doesn't work. I'm thinking its something about Codeigniter as i get a strange database error which others have seen: http://www.getfuelcms.com/forums/discussion/313/problem-with-cronjobs-%3A-database-error/p1

Comment: hi @fedorqui, ok, the problem is i wasn't using the right php binary. I followed [this forum](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/130383/) and typed `which php`. which showed that `/usr/bin/php` was not what my web application was using but rather this: `/Applications/MNPP/Library/php53/bin/php`. Nevertheless, you were correct that my problem was that I didn't specify the absolute paths in my crontab. Would you mind posting that as the answer and I'll accept. I can also post the answer if you are too busy. Thanks again!

Comment: Sure! Thank you : ) Good to read you could solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(from our comments)

Make sure you put the complete path of the file. Crontab does need absolute references.